# MVC3 Edit customer with username

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, where-clause

I am trying to edit customer with username which is using User.Identity.Name.

I don't know how to write Where condition in controller.

It looks easy. Could you help me? thanks.

Here is my coding.

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        //the username gets username through User.Identity.Name.
        string username = User.Identity.Name;

        //How can I write below coding?
        //In DB, it has userName field.

        Customer customer = db.Customer.Where(userName = username);
        return View(customer);
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to learn how [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) work:

```
.Where(c => c.UserName == username)
```

`c` is the implicitly-typed parameter.

Also, if you want a single result, you should call `FirstOrDefault()` instead; `Where()` returns a sequence.

Comment: It says cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Iqueryable<Models.Customer> to Models.Customer. What does it mean?

Comment: @wholee1: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer customer = db.Customer.Single(c=>c.UserName == username)
```

throws exception if returns one than more matching element

or

```
Customer customer = db.Customer.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.UserName == username);
```

returns null if returns more than one matching element